# javascript not returning true

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get the javascript function validate to return true... does anybody know why? My objective is to add javascript to validate the form so I can have the errors show up under the input boxes. I have achieved this part I just cannot get the validate function to return true to submit the form. I was under the impression that i need validate to return true becuuase of how i have defined the funcction in the HTML form

```
In the HTML the form is as such <form action ='reg.php' method ='POST' onsubmit='return function();'>
//markup 
</form>


 var form = document.getElementById('registration');
    var errorDisplay = document.getElementById('nameError');
    var errorEmail = document.getElementById('emailError');
    var errorPassword = document.getElementById('passwordError');
    var errorConfirmPassword = document.getElementById('passwordConfirmError');

    var validateNameField = document.getElementById('FullNameField');
    var validateEmailField = document.getElementById('emailField');
    var validatePasswordField = document.getElementById('passwordField');
    var validateConfirmPasswordField = document.getElementById('confirmPasswordField');

    validateNameField.addEventListener('blur',checkName,true);
    validateEmailField.addEventListener('blur',checkEmail,true);
    validatePasswordField.addEventListener('blur',checkPassword,true);
    validateConfirmPasswordField.addEventListener('blur',checkConfirmPassword,true);



    function checkName(){
      if(validateNameField.value !=''){
        errorDisplay.innerHTML='';
        return true;
      }
    }

    function checkEmail(){
      var emailRegEx =/\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
      if(emailRegEx.test(validateEmailField.value)){
        errorEmail.innerHTML='';
        return true;
      }
    }
    function checkPassword(){
      if(validatePasswordField.value !=''){
        errorPassword.innerHTML='';
        return true;
      }
    }
    function checkConfirmPassword(){
      if(validateConfirmPasswordField.value !=''){
        errorConfirmPassword.innerHTML='';
        return true;
      }
    }

    function validate(){

    var formFields = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var emailRegEx =/\S+@\S+\.\S+/;


        if(formFields[0].name = 'FullName' && !(formFields[0].value)){
            errorDisplay.innerHTML='name is required';
            return false;
        }

        if (formFields[1].name = 'email' && !emailRegEx.test(formFields[1].value)){
            errorEmail.innerHTML='valid email required';
            return false;
        }

        if (formFields[2].name = 'password' && !(formFields[2].value)){
            errorPassword.innerHTML='password is required';
            return false;
        }

        if (formFields[3].name = 'password_confirmed' && !(formFields[3].value)){
            errorConfirmPassword.innerHTML='confirm password is required';
            return false;
        }

        if(formFields[2].value !== formFields[3].value){
              errorConfirmPassword.innerHTML='passwrod does not mathch comfirm';
              return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
```

Comment: you are missing in else part, function will not return false if valid

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Narendra even with the else statement i am not getting a return value

Comment: What is the real, code that compiles without error, for `onsubmit='return function();'` ?

Comment: not sure what you mean but I believe my problem is that I am trying to validate with javascript and submit data via with PHP

Comment: can you be more clear with the question?? can we see your html code and also what is the outcome your expecting??

Comment: Be sure that `return function();` is invalid JavaScript.

Comment: @traktor how would I do that?

Comment: Please identify why the code 1.)  returns `true` or `undefined` for `blur` event listeners given that the return value of such listeners is not used. _and_ 2.) assigns values to the name attribute of form input elements inside `if` conditions using the assignment operator "=". Even if replaced by the logical equality operator "==", the inputs are being accessed by position and the code will break if the order of inputs is changed in HTML